# How to setup Observable.fromEvent to work with jQuery filtered events

Tags: javascript, jquery, rxjs

How can I do this? To understand Observable

```
function(button) {
var buttonClicks = Observable.fromEvent(button, "click");


var subscription =
    buttonClicks.
        forEach(function(clickEvent) {
            alert("Button was clicked. Stopping Traversal.");

            subscription.dispose();
        });

}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and clarify your question a bit more. As it is written right now, it's impossible to understand what you want to achieve. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @RandoHinn

Traversing an Event Subscribing to an Event and traversing an Array are fundamentally the same operation. The only difference is that Array traversal is synchronous and completes, and Event traversal is asynchronous and never completes. If we convert a button click Event to an Observable object, we can use forEach() to traverse the Event. Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Observable is not defined –

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message aswell, then.